# Career advice for our readers

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, implementation, diffie-hellman, algorithm-design

I am a first year math PhD student with work experience and an MS in math.  Do you have any advice regarding internships involved with cryptography and other mathematics other than the NSA? Thanks.

Comment: While I certainly would be interested in the answer of this question I do not think it's ontopic for this site.

Comment: http://www.iacr.org/jobs/

Comment: Look to the big tech companies for internship opportunities in crypto. Microsoft and IBM in particular have very impressive cryptography research labs. [Craig Gentry is employed by IBM currently.]

Comment: There are lots of smaller companies that need cryptography experts as well. For applied crypto/security, companies like Matasano are what you're looking for. Companies like Voltage Security sell specialized encryption software for business use, and employ real cryptographers. Make sure the company you're looking at sells real encryption software based on proven results. There's a lot of snake-oil encryption out there, and working for a company that sells it would most likely frustrate you greatly.

Comment: This site is really about the theory and practice of cryptography. This sort of question really doesn't fit the topic matter we are interested in.

Comment: Thanks. I know this is not an appropriate place to ask this, but I'm not sure where else I could get such specialized advice outside of academia...  Thank you again for the feedback.

Comment: There is a **meta** tag on the other stackexchange sites which might be useful for this type of question.